# Using both Random Forest and RFE for Feature Selection and Dimensionality Reduction

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, random-forest, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I am using random forest classifier currently to do feature selection for a balanced dataset of about 18K rows and 7050 features. I recognize this is a lot of features.

I am thinking of using random forest to select an arbitrary number of features (200-300) and then use recursive feature elimination to feature select even further.

What are some problems that I should prepare for when running this type of "ensemble" feature selection?

Comment: It would help if you explained the larger goal

Comment: My dataset is mostly a bunch of dummy variables. Some variables are highly correlated to each other because they are really part of a broader category. I've decided to only run RF on the variables that are not part of the broader category since RF selects variables that are highly correlated first and then discards the others that are correlated. Using that output of features selected from RF, . I would like to avoid overfitting yet pick features with high p-values, high relative importance contributing to a model with high F1 and accuracy scores. (I know, cliche.)